# Eve - Is it possible to unset a key from a document?

Tags: eve

In a schema with optional values such as `code` in the example:

```
'code': {
    'type': 'string',
},
'name': {
    'type': 'string',
    'required': True,
},
'email': {
    'type': 'string',
    'required': True
}
```

Let's say there's an inserted document with a value for `code`. Can I unset the `code` key like `mongodb $unset` does, using Eve somehow?

Comment: The snippet is a cerberus schema, used in eve to validate API documents. What I want is to remove the key via API calls.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to setup a [default projection](http://python-eve.org/config.html#limiting-the-fieldset-exposed-by-the-api-endpoint) for the endpoint.

> Limiting the Fieldset Exposed by the API Endpoint
>   By default API responses to GET requests will include all fields defined by the corresponding resource schema. The projection setting of the datasource resource keyword allows you to redefine the fields.

```
people = {
    'datasource': {
        'projection': {'username': 1}
    }
}
```

> The above setting will expose only the username field to GET requests, no matter the schema defined for the resource.

Another option is to leverage MongoDB Aggregation Framework itself. Just set the endpoint so that a aggregation is performed before data is returned to the client. The following should work (see the [docs](http://python-eve.org/features.html#mongodb-aggregation-framework) for details):

```
posts = {
    'datasource': {
        'aggregation': {
            'pipeline': [{"$unset": "code"}]
        }
    }
}
```

You need Eve v0.7 for aggregation support.

Comment: Thanks for the help Nicola. I think I didn't explain it correctly. In some documents for the same schema the field may exist, so it's not a general rule for all documents, but an optional field in fact. Imagine the key may exist, and later on after an event, it should be removed from the document.

Comment: Added an alternative approach which might work for your use case.

Comment: I should be missing something, but I couldn't make the second option work. I've added the datasource for the document schema but a GET for the resource still shows `code`. Should the request be changed too in that case? And if working, wouldn't that unset `code` for all documents? Thanks again.

Comment: You need v0.7 (which is currently on development branch)

Comment: OK, I tried but still no luck. After adding this to the schema, do I need to set any value to `aggregate` key during the request?
If so, how the document to unset the key is chosen?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do it with a PATCH request, but a PUT request should do.

```
import requests

# get original doc
resp = requests.get(document_url)

# prepare a new document
doc = resp.json()
new_doc = {k: v for k, v in doc.items() if not k.startswith('_')}
del new_doc['code']

# overwrite the complete document
resp = requests.put(document_url, json=new_doc, headers={'If-Match': doc['_etag']}
```