# How to unset field from Python Eve application?

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, eve

Is there a way to unset a field from document using Eve framework?

Like `$ curl -X PATCH http://example.com/people/<id> -d '{"image": "$unset": 1}'`

Comment: If you have Eve 0.7, there's a possible solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088047/eve-is-it-possible-to-unset-a-key-from-a-document), but I couldn't make it work in my case.

Comment: Aggregation does not solve this problem, what I ask is if exists any form to delete a key from document

Answer (score 0):

Eve doesn't have some built-in thing for this, but you can use [Event hooks](http://python-eve.org/features.html#event-hooks) to handle resource update event, find out fields which should be replaced and replace them by yourself.